# Does I give instructions to Dji Phantom 4 using onboard sdk

Tags: linux, sdk, ros, dji-sdk

I have Dji Phantom 4 and I need to track object using it so can I give instructions to it using onboard sdk as its only for Matrice 100 and if not is there any other way to five it instructions using ROS or with linux operating system.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit unclear and way too vague for this site. Please try to clarify it and narrow it down to a specific technical question. Then you may get help here.

Answer (score 0):

With a Phantom 4, you can't use the OnboardSDK.

To achieve what you want your best chance is the [MobileSDK](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/). 
It's available on iOS and Android though.

With it, you can get the video feed of the camera and do the tracking you want, convert it into virtual stick commands and have the drone track visually the subject you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you suggest ho to use virtual stick to send roll and pitch commands to drone

Comment: It's a little tricky to show you all here, but on iOS this is the piece of documentation you want to look into: http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController.html#djiflightcontroller_virtualstickcontrolmodecategory_sendvirtualstickflightcontroldata_inline